# Views, subviews, root views, tabbarcontrollers, navbarcontrollers, woah! A diagram appraoch?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Sometimes just when I think got it, i get knocked back 2 steps. Like now add this block of code with a tabbarcontroller to this page, but with an edit button, and scrap that nav bar for a tabbar, but 1/2 is built in IB, the rest is built in code. yipes, sometimes it can get a bit nuts to make sense of it all.

Has anyone found a nice reference to this visually?  Like how do you think about the layers of all these objects?  Is there a visualization of the workings of the iPhone that someone recommends highly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation may help you think about your application's organization in a visual manner.

Answer (score 3):

trying to get a hang of it all from the beginning can be a bit overwhelming, considering all that's available to you.  Especially since the views are all designed with so much flexibility that you can put almost anything anywhere and add as many or as few layers as you want in any order that you see fit.

Aside from the documentation, sometimes seeing example code can be very helpful.

Here's a neat tool that'll turn a nib/xib into its respective code:

http://github.com/akosma/nib2objc

With it, you can experiment and play around in Interface Builder, then see what the equivalent Obj-C code would be for it.

Play around long enough and you should get a good idea of what goes where.

Comment: thanks, will give it a try. looks cool.  really love objc after years with the all other web guys. Just entering year 2 with it. learning something new everyday.

Comment: np.  there's just no short answer to your question.  you can stick a custom UIViewController inside a UIView inside a UITableViewCell inside another UIView managed by a UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController.... who knows... and it's that flexibility that makes learning view hierarchies confusing in the beginning, but awesome in the end